# How can i synchronize these 3 promise-based functions?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

How can i synchronize these 3 promise returning functions (For example in other function)? I want to get following output -> Start -> (2secs)..2..(3secs)..3..(4secs)..4 -> End. I've tryed Generators, but my output wasn't like that (Probably i did something wrong)

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved 2');
      console.log('2')
    }, 2000);
  });
}
function resolveAfter3Seconds() {
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved 2');
      console.log('3')
    }, 3000);
  });
}
function resolveAfter4Seconds() {
 new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved 2');
      console.log('4')
    }, 4000);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change the functions to return their promises. For example:

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => { // <------ added return statement
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved 2');
      console.log('2')
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

Then either chain the promises together

```
resolveAfter2Seconds()
  .then(() => resolveAfter3Seconds())
  .then(() => resolveAfter4Seconds());
```

Or use async/await syntax:

```
async function exampleFunction() {
  await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  await resolveAfter3Seconds();
  await resolveAfter4Seconds();
}
```

Comment: FYI: `.then(() => resolveAfter3Seconds())` === `.then(resolveAfter3Seconds)`

Comment: @NicholasTower your point is also good, but the behaviour is the same in this particular case since these functions don't take any arguments.

Comment: Yeah, i deleted my comment since it didn't really matter. Thanks @RandyCasburn for demonstrating a more concise alternative.

Comment: It's funny, but i done it in same way and it didnt work. Now i pasted your solution with then() and it works. Thank You (Probably i did in past something strange with that)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try chaining to get the sequential output:

```
resolveAfter2Seconds()
  .then(() => resolveAfter3Seconds())
  .then(() => resolveAfter4Seconds())
```

PS. Don't forget to make those functions return promises.

Comment: FYI: `.then(() => resolveAfter3Seconds())` === `.then(resolveAfter3Seconds)`